# In Angular 2, how do I switch glyphicons AND fire their functions? *ngIf?

Tags: angular

I'm designing a simple 'favorite' functionality for my Angular 2 app. The code fragment below correctly displays either glyphicon-star or glyphicon-star-empty based on the objects current status. It also fires the corresponding function to favorite / un-favorite the object.

However I also need them to switch status after firing, without needing to reload the whole thing. A 'star' div would fire 'unfavoriteView(v.id)' and then switch to a 'star-empty' div, which in turn would fire 'favoriteView(v.id)' when clicked and switch back to the 'star' div.

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<div *ngIf="v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal == 1">
  <a (click)="unfavoriteView(v.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a>
</div>

<div *ngIf="v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal == 0">
  <a (click)="favoriteView(v.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the HTML a little more concise.

```
<a (click)="toggleFavorite(v.id)">
  <span *ngIf="v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal == 1" 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a>
  <span *ngIf="v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal == 0" 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
</a>
```

Instead of having two functions for favorize and unfavorize you now have only the `toggleFavorite()`, which is in control of everything. Switching the star glyphicon works implicitly when you change your `v.usage.favoritesTotal`

Comment: `toggleFavorite` is definitely better than having 2 functions! I took the liberty of rewriting it a little to `toggleFavorite(v.id, v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal)` to distinguish between the two states. But the glyphicons don't switch for some reason...

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr?

Comment: Ah, never mind it was unrelated to your answer (the value `v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal` didn't update like it should).

Answer (score 1):

You could switch classes on that `favoritesTotal` expression with `ngClass`:

```html
<div *ngIf="v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal == 0">
  <a (click)="toggleFavoriteView(v.id, v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal == 0)">
    <span [ngClass]="['glyphicon', v.usageInfo.favoritesTotal == 0
                                 ? 'glyphicon-star-empty'
                                 : 'glyphicon-star']"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And in your code:

```ts
toggleFavoriteView(id, favorite: boolean) {
    if (favorite) {
        favoriteView(id);
    }
    else {
        unfavoriteView(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really love uncommented downvotes - I will never know what the caster found to be wrong :D :(